# Spring Data Repository caching results

Tags: caching, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am a complete spring data noob. I have an interface as follows

```
public interface UserBalanceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserBalance, Integer>
{
    @Cachable("UserList")
    @Query("select userId from UserBalance")
    List<Integer> ListUserIds(Pageable pageable);
}
```

My cache configuration looks like this:

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

<!-- generic cache manager -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
  <property name="caches">
    <set>
      <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean" p:name="UserList"/>
    </set>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The caching does absolutely nothing. I guess it is because the proxied class does not have the @Cachable annotation, but how do I make the caching work? Is there a different way to do caching?

My last resort will be to put the calls that need to be cached inside a wrapper class and cache there.

Comment: What does your caching setup look like?

Comment: Very basic. I just used the books example. But from what I understand the issue is that AspecJ will not fire pointcuts there were made on an interface.

Comment: There's no AspectJ involved at all. Please add your caching configuration as otherwise it's hard to judge what's going on. Using `@Cacheable` works as you showed if you just configure caching correctly.

Comment: I added the cache config and it works if it is not on the Repository interface

Comment: I've created an example using Spring Data repositories alongside the caching abstractions to our examples repo: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/example/repository/caching/CachingRepositoryTests.java

Comment: Cool, thanks... That worked a charm. Why does Java config work but the XML config did not?

Comment: It actually should. I'll alter the example to run with XML as well and collect that stuff in an answer :).

Comment: Oh well... it's working now. And here we prefer Java config over XML. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Your code is the same with mine. I am using eclipseLink and i had to enable caching on persistence.xml too. I just added a property,

```
        [...]
        <class>com.project.web.model.entity.ReturnOrder</class>
        <class>com.project.web.model.entity.BillingAddress</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://connection string"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>

            <!-- PROPERTY ADDED -->
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also, [this](http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/5-minutes-with-spring-cache/) is a very good tutorial.