# Spring Data + Hibernate Query Caching not working

Tags: hibernate, caching, jpa, ehcache, spring-data

I am trying but not succeeding to cache a query in **Spring Data** and **Hibernate** environmet with following **dependencies** :

```
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.0.0.GA'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.6.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.3.1.GA'
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.2.0.RELEASE'
```

### My Spring Data Repository(ServiceRepository) for entity Service is

```
public interface ServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Service, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Service> {
    @Cacheable("merchantServices")
    @Query("select s from Service s JOIN s.statusList sas where s.status=?1 and s.priviligedUser.priviligedUserType IN (2,4) and (s.id IN (select st.id from Service st inner join st.tags tag where tag IN (?3)) or s.serviceType IN (?2)) and sas.active=true and sas.transactorType=?4 ORDER BY s.name")
    List<Service> getAllMerchantServicesByStatusTypeAndTags(ServiceStatus status, List<ServiceType> type, List<String> tags, TransactorType transactor);
}
```

### Repository's @Cacheable method being invoked from

```
public List<Service> getAllServicesByStatusAndId(ServiceStatus status, List<Long> services, TransactorType transactor) {
    return serviceRepository.getAllMerchantServicesByStatusAndServiceId(status, services, transactor);
}
```

### My Caching confing (jpa-context.xml) is

It is inspired from [spring-data-jpa-examples/src/main/resources/caching-repository-context.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/main/resources/caching-repository-context.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
      <property name="caches">
         <set>
          <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="merchantServices"/>
        </set>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### cache enabled Hibernate config (hibernate.cfg.xml) is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">16</property>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Looking at log; every time I request, I see query executed.

```
17:50:28.997 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: select s from Service s JOIN s.statusList sas where s.status=?1 and s.priviligedUser.priviligedUserType IN (2,4) and s.id IN (?2) and sas.active=true and sas.transactorType=?3 ORDER BY s.name, time: 57ms, rows: 1
```

Next time I request, I see following query;

```
18:03:40.374 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: select s from Service s JOIN s.statusList sas where s.status=?1 and s.priviligedUser.priviligedUserType IN (2,4) and s.id IN (?2) and sas.active=true and sas.transactorType=?3 ORDER BY s.name, time: 47ms, rows: 1
```

### References

[spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples/tree/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/example/repository/caching)

[Spring 3.1 Caching and Config](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/09/spring-31-caching-and-config.html#.Ujl-iIoW3uk)

[Spring Data Rest - Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18363810/432903)

[Spring Data Repository caching results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17896118/432903)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<cache:annotation-driven />` in `jpa-context.xml` was missing, adding which fixes the problem . The final `jpa-context.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
      <property name="caches">
         <set>
          <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="merchantServices"/>
        </set>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I also added `resources/ehcache.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

<diskStore path="/home/prayag/cache_"/>
<defaultCache
        eternal="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="true"
        timeToLiveSeconds="300"
        />
</ehcache>
```

Which is referenced as `<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</property>` in `resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`.

#### My CPU cache conf is

```
prayag@prayag:~/hacker_/draobkcalb$ sudo dmidecode -t cache
[sudo] password for prayag: 
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: Internal Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Unknown
    System Type: Unknown
    Associativity: Unknown

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: External Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: External
    Installed Size: 2048 kB
    Maximum Size: 2048 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Unknown
    System Type: Unknown
    Associativity: Unknown
```

Comment: isn't this a spring thing, and not a jpa thing? as in, you're not using the query cache here at all really

Comment: For this answer, what does the CPU cache here try to indicate?  The hibernate level 1/2 cache should have nothing to do with CPU cache.